# How to make Mongoose array of object ID reference in side a object with unknown keys of parent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-design, mongoose-schema

here I present some json objects which will be save to a schema.

`Article Schema design:`

```
const Article = new Schema({
  postBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  contents: {
    type: Map,
    of: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Content"
  }
})
```

Because in the `Article`, each document has unknown amounts of language inside. So I cannot set as:

```
contents: {
  en: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Content"
  }],
  jp: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Content"
  }],
...
}
```

If I would like to save the record to `Article`, the error message will return:

```
message: "Articles validation failed: contents.en: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[ 620e18b647a8f541892f3046, 620e18b847a8f541892f3048 ]\" (type Array) at path \"contents.$*\", contents.jp: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[ 620e18b847a8f541892f304a, 620e18b847a8f541892f304c ]\" (type Array) at path \"contents.$*\""
name: "ValidationError"
```

Does anyone can help to design the schema can support unknow amounts of language, and the language keys are dynamic. And then can save references objectId into the `content[keys]` to make a relation between `Article` schema and `Content` schema?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
const Article = new Schema({
  postBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  contents: {
    type: Map,
    of: {
        type: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Content"
            }
        ]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

```
  entry:{
    type:[new Schema({},{versionKey:false,strict:false,_id:false})],
    required:false,
    default:[]
  },
```

this is the way to create an array of arbitrary objects i can think of